# CORS on WCF issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, wcf, cors

I developed RESTFull Post Web Service.
Test this service via Chrome Extension, all OK.
Now I want to call this service from ajax or Angular JS. Exactly want angular js.

I know need to enable CROS on server side.
I have practive JAX-RS 2 enable on server.

For WCF I read http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html forum and done step by step. Then I tested service via Chrome Extension, noticed that header are changed.

But from angular js the same error.
which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

Do you have any IDEA?

Answer (score 1):

There are some manuals like

http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/05/15/implementing-cors-support-in-wcf.aspx

But the easiest way is to use Web API 2 instead WCF with CORS Library (easiest for developing, but you have to use .NET4.5)

http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html